# Установка и настройка Redmine+Ngnix+thin

Tags: установка, настройка, redmine, freebsd

Добрый вечер.

Бьюсь с редймайном уже достаточно длительное время.
До этого момента я установил redmine в связке с апачем и пассажиром. Но результат меня не впечатлил, а точнее просто поверг в шок - скорость обработки просто бесконечно медленная, особенно при старте, хотя проблему при старте я решил.

Начал искать решение, как бы сделать, чтобы мой редмайн шустренько бегал - перелопатил кучу информации и пришел к выводу, что нужно запустить redmine в связке с ngnix+thin.
Тут опять кучу информации перелопатить пришлось касаемо ngnix. Все вроде бы поставил, настроил, попробовал запустить phpmyadmin - все получилось.

А вот насчет как установить и увязать redmine с thin, информации оказалось не так много. И победить запуск redmine в связке с ngnix+thin мне не удалось, и я уже почти сдался. Поэтому прошу помощи, если кому приходилось настраивать в такой связке - просьба сказать, как, в каком порядке?

Вот что я нашел и что мне не помогло:

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_configure_Nginx_to_run_Redmine

http://blackpenguins.ru/?p=668

После настройки ngnix порядок действий был следующий:

1. gem install thin, получил ответ что-то вроде:

> Successfully
>
> ```
> unable to convert "\ xC3" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
> ```
>
> to US-A
>
> ```
> SCII for CHANGELOG, skipping
>
> 1 gem installed
> ```

1. Добавил строки ngnix.conf:

   ```
   upstream thin_cluster {

   server unix:/tmp/thin.0.sock;

   }

   server {

   listen 80;

   server_name mysite.ru;

   access_log /var/log/nginx/redmine-proxy-access;

   error_log /var/log/nginx/redmine-proxy-error;

   charset utf-8;

   root /disk2/www/redmine/public;

   proxy_redirect off;

   proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

   client_max_body_size 50m;

   client_body_buffer_size 10m;

   proxy_connect_timeout 90;

   proxy_send_timeout 90;

   proxy_read_timeout 90;

   proxy_buffer_size 4k;

   proxy_buffers 4 32k;

   proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;

   proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;

   location / {

   try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @cluster;

   }

   location @cluster {

   proxy_pass http://thin_cluster;

   }

   }
   ```
2. Создал директорию и файл /etc/thin/redmine.yml с содержимым:

   ```
   pid: tmp/pids/thin.pid

   group: redmine

   wait: 30

   timeout: 30

   log: log/thin.log

   max_conns: 1024

   require: []

   environment: production

   max_persistent_conns: 512

   servers: 1

   daemonize: true

   user: redmine

   socket: /tmp/thin.sock

   chdir: /disk2/www/redmine
   ```
3. И все, не знаю, что делать дальше? Redmine не работает.
4. Вот информация о redmine:

   ```
   darcs: not found

   hg: not found

   cvs: not found

   bzr: not found

   git: not found

   Environment:

   Redmine version 2.6.0.stable.13591

   Ruby version 2.0.0-p576 (2014-09-19) [i386-freebsd10]

   Rails version 3.2.20

   Environment production

   Database adapter Mysql2

   SCM:

   Subversion 1.8.10

   Filesystem

   Redmine plugins:

   redmine_agile 1.3.5

   redmine_better_gantt_chart 0.9.0

   redmine_checklists 3.0.1

   redmine_dmsf 1.4.9 stable

   redmine_people 0.1.8

   ОС Freebsd 10
   ```

Comment: @bolahg, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 1):

Вам бы сначала ознакомиться с общими требованиями для установки и настройки:
redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall

Не хватает базовой диагностической информации для решения Вашего вопроса, например запущены ли службы, делали ли вы миграцию бд, хватает ли всех гемов для приложения.

Также приложу [статью](http://redmine-git-hosting.io/how-to/install-redmine/), где достаточно пошагово расписана установка и настройка, где в случае использования веб-сервера puma вам достаточно использовать thin. и да. рекомендую использовать стабильный релиз redmine.

В случае, если вам совсем лениво заморачиваться с различными зависимостями пакетов то вот [эти](https://bitnami.com/stack/redmine) добрые люди собрали само-распаковывающийся-и-настроенный-для работы пакет за вас.
Приятной работы!